# Record read only based on field create/update from external system

Tags: trigger, javascript, workflow, validation

We have SFDC - Employee Integration with external HR System, Question is  when we receive back the  ‘Employee Identifier’ from HR System, I need to make the employee record read only? pls suggest suitable soultion.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to add a checkbox field `Is_Read_Only__c`.  Then put a trigger on the Object.  Before update, look at that field, and if it is true, stop the operation for that record by adding an error.

```
for(Id id : Trigger.newMap.keySet()){
    //Make sure this isn't the update that is setting the flag for the first time. 
    if(Trigger.oldMap.get(id).Is_Read_Only__c && Trigger.newMap.get(id).Is_Read_Only__c){
        Trigger.oldMap.get(id).addError('Record Id ' + id = ' is marked as read-only and cannot be edited);
    }
}
```